# Determine the eigenvalues of $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ .

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that
 $a_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
i, & \quad \text{if } i+j=n+1\\
0 ,& \quad \text{otherwise. } \\
\end{cases}$

Then what will be the Eigen value of $A?$

MY TRY:I am unable to proceed a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try squaring the matrix, and you will have that the diagonal entries are $a_{i\times i}=i\cdot(n-i)$. This gives a recipe for a polynomial equation in $A$. For $n$ even, that is
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}(A^2-i\cdot(n-i+1))=0
\end{equation*}
For $n$ odd, that is
\begin{equation*}
\left(A^2-\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2\right)\prod_{i=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(A^2-i\cdot(n-i+1))=0
\end{equation*}
Thus in all cases we have eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{i\cdot(n-i+1)}$ for $i=1,2,..., \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$. That is all the eigenvalues in the even case. In the odd case there is one more: $\frac{n+1}{2}$ (and it is positive because there is an obvious eigenvector).

Comment: What will be the case if $A_{n\times n} = \begin {bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end {bmatrix}?$

Comment: Have you tried squaring that matrix? What is the result when you square it?

Comment: Yes ,I think $A^2=I   $ for any order.

Comment: Exactly! That means $A^2-I=0$, so all eigenvalues must be either $1$ or $-1$. Can you find an eigenvector for each value?

Comment: So,Minimal polynomial of this matrix is $x^2-1=0$.but can we conclude characteristics polynomial?

Comment: It's going to be hard to spell this out in the comments. Perhaps ask another question. 

The result is probably dependent on even or odd; however, $(x^2-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$ is probably a large factor of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Ok,Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the given situation the matrix $A_{n\times n} $ matrix can be described as 
$$A_{n\times n} = \begin {bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 3 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots\\
n & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end {bmatrix} $$

We can check that a pair of eigenvalues will be definitely $\pm \sqrt{n}$. Can you check that out? Hope it helps.